# Custom read and write method in GSON library

Tags: java, json, gson

HI i have following JSON

`{
"name":"testapp2",
"type":"Web",
"packageName":"test2.com",
"secretKey":{"0987654321","91287465827"},
"otpExpiry":"1800",
"senderId":"VERIFY",
"otpLength":"4",
"requestPerIp":"500",
"signature":"#OTP is your verification code"
}`

I am writing my custom JSON reader and writer this is my code overrding GSON TypeAdapter class here is my code.I am trying to catch my JSON object and convert it into my Custom Model class ... Basically i want to parse the nested json object

```
public Application read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
Application application = new Application();
String secKey=null;
reader.beginObject();
while (reader.hasNext()) {
  String name = reader.nextName();
  switch (name) {
    case "type":
      ApplicationType type = new ApplicationType(reader.nextString());
      application.setType(type);
      break;
    case "packageName":
      application.setPackageName(reader.nextString());
      break;
    case "otpExpiry":
      application.setOtpExpiry(reader.nextInt());
      break;
    case "name":
      application.setName(reader.nextString());
      break;
    case "senderId":
      application.setSenderId(reader.nextString());
      break;
    case "otpLength":
      application.setOtpLength(reader.nextInt());
      break;
    case "requestPerIp":
      application.setRequestPerIp(reader.nextLong());
      break;
    case "secretKey":
      reader.beginArray();
      while (reader.hasNext())
       secKey+=reader.nextString();
      application.setSecretKey(secKey);
      break;
    case "signature":
      application.setSignature(reader.nextString());
      break;
    case "sendOTPInResponse":
      application.setSendOTPInResponse(reader.nextInt());
      break;
    default:
      reader.skipValue();
      break;
  }
}
reader.endObject();
return application;
```

This method is not able to parse .. please help...

Comment: ""secretKey":{"0987654321","91287465827"}"  this is not an array.

Comment: ["0987654321","91287465827"] i changed to this but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First, you have invalid JSON: the `secretKey` is declared as an object, not as an array.
- Second, you forgot close the array in `case "secretKey"`: `reader.endArray();`.
- Third, the `secKey` variable is declared as `null`, thus it must be an empty string `""` in order not to add the leading `"null"` token to the `secretKey` field.

However, custom stream reading is perfect for huge data sets processing, but you seem to better have simple deserialization strategy and delegate tedious deserialization job directly to Gson:

Let's say, the deserialization method is defined as follows:

```java
static Application deserializeApplication(final JsonReader reader) {
    return gson.<ApplicationIncomingDto>fromJson(reader, ApplicationIncomingDto.class).application();
}
```

A special case here is `ApplicationType` that is stored as string in your JSON, but requires to be converted to `ApplicationType`. So a `GsonBuilder` should be used, so that:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(ApplicationType.class, (JsonDeserializer<ApplicationType>) (json, typeOfT, context) -> new ApplicationType(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString()))
        .create();
```

where you can bind the `ApplicationType` class and a custom `JsonDeserializer` implementation compliant with your needs. The bellow code snippet declares a custom *data transfer object* designed specially for data deserialization and then to be converted to your `Application` class. However, you might deserialize directly to `Application`, but usually it's not that a good idea (say, you can annotate the DTO class fields with Gson-like annotations; or switch to another JSON library, and leave the `Application` class as it is).

```java
private static final class ApplicationIncomingDto {

    private final String name = null;
    private final ApplicationType type = null;
    private final String packageName = null;
    private final Integer otpExpiry = null;
    private final String senderId = null;
    private final Integer otpLength = null;
    private final Long requestPerIp = null;
    private final List<String> secretKey = null;
    private final String signature = null;

    private Application application() {
        final Application application = new Application();
        application.setName(name);
        application.setType(type);
        application.setPackageName(packageName);
        application.setOtpExpiry(otpExpiry);
        application.setSenderId(senderId);
        application.setOtpLength(otpLength);
        application.setRequestPerIp(requestPerIp);
        application.setSecretKey(secretKey.stream().collect(Collectors.joining()));
        application.setSignature(signature);
        return application;
    }

}
```

And finally, the way it can be used:

```java
out.println(deserializeApplication(new JsonReader(new StringReader(JSON))));
```

Output (considering `toString()` is overridden both for `Application` and `ApplicationType`):

> Application{type=ApplicationType{name='Web'}, packageName='test2.com', otpExpiry=1800, name='testapp2', senderId='VERIFY', otpLength=4, requestPerIp=500, secretKey='098765432191287465827', signature='#OTP is your verification code', sendOTPInResponse=0}

Comment: Thanks very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Please use GSON Library, that provide Conversion from  JSONString into your Model

You need to create your model and pass your jsonString

Here you create ModelCalss

```
public class Store  {
public String StoreId;
public String StoreDisplayLink;
public String StoreAddress;
```

}

GSON library will map your JSONString into your Model

```
 private Store getStoreModel(String jsonStore) {

    Type type = new TypeToken<Store>() {
    }.getType();
    Store store = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStore, type);
    return store;
```

}

for more information visit that link

[enter link description here](https://github.com/google/gson)